# Using changeset on another solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

We have two solutions which share same code base.
Although it is "bad practice" and they should be referencing to the same base, they are not.

I've added a new feature to the base of one solution, now I want to take the changeset and apply it to another solution.
They are both under the same team project (but diffrent solutions).

What I am doing now is using external program to compare between the two solutions and going applying the changes manualy one by one.

Maybe there is a better solution in VS2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **branches** to accomplish the goal. [How to branch folders and files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files)

Since a codebase that is forked into various branches. After you added a new feature in one branch, you can directly merge the changeset to another branch. [How to Merge folders and files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-folders-files)

Finally, you can also [compare folders and files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/compare-folders-files) to make sure all changes sync up.

Comment: Thank you for the links, is it possible to merge a branch of solution A, to solution B? (A &B being diffrent projects on same TFS)

Comment: There is a thing called **baseless merge**. Doing the merge will get a warning " A merge relationship does not exist between the source and the target. A baseless merge will be performed. "